# Unity - Can't SignIn in Google Play Games with my App

Tags: android, authentication, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I have published an app to Google Play and I would like to add a leaderboard to it now.
I followed some tutorials about it (on GitHub) but I still can't sign in:

```
void SignIn()
{
    Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => 
        {
            if(success)
                GameObject.Find("UI_TXT_NAME").GetComponent<Text>().text = Social.localUser.userName;
            else
            {
                GameObject.Find("UI_TXT_NAME").GetComponent<Text>().text = "Inconnu";
                Debug.Log("Fail to authenticate");
            }
        });
}
```

When I build and run my app on my Android Phone, this code always ends in the "else{}" statement.
Yet, after trying to Sign In, I can see the green pop-up frame from Google Play Games but authentication doesn't seem to work.
And of course I can't show the Leaderboard.

I found lots of thread on various forums about this issue but none of the answers works with me.

- I do have downloaded the latest Android packages (yesterday).
- I have no errors nor error messages.
- I do have registered my app and copied the resources in the unity Window->Google Play Games->Setup->Android Setup.
- I do have created the leaderboard in Google Play.
- I do have allowed my two mail addresses to test my apps.

I must be missing something...

Subsidiary question: Is it possible to Sign In Google Play Games in Unity play mode or do I have to run it on my mobile phone every time?

Comment: Yes, you must run it on your mobile phone.

Comment: Try putting the apk in play store and downloading it from there instead of using "build and run"

Comment: FIrst i thought i had already done it... But today I tried again and it worked. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate on Android you must initialize Google Play Games(not necessary for iOS).
The code necessary for GPG initialization (Android only):

```
    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new 
    PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
        .Build();
    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
```

And then signing in (Android and iOS):

```
void SignIn()
{
    Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => 
        {
            if(success)
                GameObject.Find("UI_TXT_NAME").GetComponent<Text>().text = 
Social.localUser.userName;
            else
            {
                GameObject.Find("UI_TXT_NAME").GetComponent<Text>().text = "Inconnu";
                Debug.Log("Fail to authenticate");
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have already these initialization codelines in my program... Yet it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

It now works (almost) properly. The solution seemed to be downloading the App from the Google Store and not "build and run" it... I thought I had done it before but today it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Now it is the 
Social.ReportScore (lScore, "Cgklwq6hv_sUEAIQAA", (bool success)...)

that doesn't work. Yet success ends with "true" but my leaderboard stays empty...